# Add call history entry like whatsapp does

Tags: ios, whatsapp, callkit

We wrote an VoIP application and we like to add call history entry in 'Recent' calls like whatsapp does.

If you make a Whatsapp call, a call log entry will be added in 'Recent' with "Whatsapp Audio" remarks. Clicking on it automatically launches whatsapp and call is placed to that number.

I couldn't find any API to achieve this. However since whatsapp is doing it, I am sure there are APIs to add entry and then intercept.

Any idea?

Comment: I think it’s this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/230/

Answer (score 2):

To include calls made using your VoIP app in the Phone app's Recents tab, as well as participate in the system's native incoming call UI and other features, use the new CallKit framework in iOS 10 and later.

Check out the [WWDC 2016 session 230 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/230/) for more details, or see the [official documentation for CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit). Also, the [Speakerbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code app demonstrates many best practices for using CallKit.